# Using var for a switch case

Tags: c++, menu

I have to do a C++ program to manage bank accounts. But i'm stuck. I need to display the different accounts, to select one and do some stuff on the selected account. I'm doing the choice in a switch case but i would like the "case" to be dynamic (an other part of the program is made for adding account)

```
    switch (choixMenu)
    {
    case 1:
        //Consulter un compte
        do {
            cout << endl << " ----------------------- CONSULTATION -----------------------" << endl << endl;
            cout << "Choisir le compte a consulter : \n" << endl;
            while (nCompte != NULL) {
                int numCompte = 1;
                int *ptr (0);
                ptr = &numCompte;
                cout << numCompte << " - " << nCompte << cid << endl;
                numCompte++;
                switch (choixConsul) {
                case ptr :
                }
            }
            cin >> choixMenu;

            if (choixMenu != 1 && choixMenu != 2 && choixMenu != 3)
            {
                cout << "Choix invalide !" << endl;
            }

        } while (choixConsul != 3);
```

(compte = account)
Is there any way to do the case with a var? A loop to display the different account and a case in a loop to select every account? 
Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Sorry i wrongly deleted "Hi everyone!" while posting it  :(

Comment: That wasn't _"wrongly deleted"_ for sure. It's OK.

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic solution is to use tables:

```
struct Menu_Entry
{
  std::string option_text;
  void (*p_action_function)();
}

std::vector<Menu_Entry> menu;
```

With a table driven system, you could have one function that displays all the selections, then dereferences a function pointer associated with the menu choice.

Several menus can be displayed and processed by passing a vector of menu selections to the menu processing function.

The `std::string` could be replaced with an array of characters in order to allow for static constant data.